# 'thisArg' parameter in Array.prototype.map

Tags: javascript, this

[mdn document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) about `Array.prototype.map` says like below

> `arr.map(callback[, thisArg])`
> If a thisArg parameter is provided to map, it will be used as callback's this value. Otherwise, the value undefined will be used as its this value. The this value ultimately observable by callback is determined according to the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function.

What is `this` value, `undefined` or another value determined by usual rules?

In addition, `this` in `Array.map`'s callback is `undefined` when using in class.

```
class Sample {
  constructor() {
    this.list = [1, 2, 3];
  }
  mapList() {
    this.list.map(function(x) {
      console.log(this); 
    });
  }
}
const obj = new Sample();
obj.mapList();    // `this` is undefined
```

but it's window when using in function. Why `this` in two cases is different despite same `thisArgs` value?

```
function Sample() {
  this.list = [1, 2, 3];
}
Sample.prototype.mapList = function() {
  return this.list.map(function(x) {
    console.log(this); 
  });
}
const obj = new Sample();
obj.mapList();  // `this` is window(global object)
```

I know that this is highly frequently asked question in SO and some users will check this question as duplicate, but I have to ask this question because of my poor understanding.

I just want to know about why `this` is undefined in above code that uses class, not about solutions(`bind`, `arrow funtion` things). Can anyone help me?

Comment: That's exactly "the usual rules". ES6 classes are strict mode, so when a function is called with `undefined` for the `this` value it shows up as that; while in sloppy mode the `this` keyword becomes the global object when passing in `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi Just passed value is `undefined` and `this` value is determined according to rules in sloppy mode. Is it okay to understand this way?

Comment: Yes. The same argument applies to passing in a bound function or an arrow function: the passed value ("thisArg") is `undefined`, but the `this` inside the function is determined by the usual rules (resolved to the bound thisArg or lexically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

> The bodies of class declarations and class expressions are executed in
>   **strict mode** i.e. constructor, static and prototype methods, getter and
>   setter functions are executed in strict mode.

In strict mode context if unspecified is undefined.

> ... the value passed as this to a function in strict mode is not forced into being an object (a.k.a. "boxed")
>   ...Thus for a strict mode function, the specified this is not boxed into
>   an object, and if unspecified, this will be undefined

If you add `"use strict"` to the second example it will be `undefined` as well.